# Will this tag make a [scene] on the way out?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scene) tag currently has 783 questions. Its own tag Wiki condemns it:

> 'scene' can refer to various things. Please combine this tag with other tags to put your question into perspective.

"Can refer to various things" and "must be combined with another tag to be meaningful" are both reasons to remove the tag.

I literally have no idea what this tag is even supposed to mean.

A few examples of what this tag is being used for:

- JavaFX scenes
- Unity scenes
- Movie/video players "in general"
- Spritekit scenes
- Corona
- MoviePy
- OpenGL

And that's just on the first page. Who's to say that one of those uses is more "correct" than any of the others?

I'm not convinced that these are sufficiently similar to merit keeping this tag around. To begin with, I don't see much evidence that understanding what a scene is in one framework will automatically lend itself to understanding what a scene is in another framework.

For reference, here's [a definition of what a JavaFX scene is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html):

> The JavaFX Scene class is the container for all content in a scene graph.

A scene graph is [defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/scenegraph/jfxpub-scenegraph.htm) as:

> A scene graph is a tree data structure, most commonly found in graphical applications and libraries such as vector editing tools, 3D libraries, and video games. The JavaFX scene graph is a retained mode API, meaning that it maintains an internal model of all graphical objects in your application. At any given time, it knows what objects to display, what areas of the screen need repainting, and how to render it all in the most efficient manner. Instead of invoking primitive drawing methods directly, you instead use the scene graph API and let the system automatically handle the rendering details. This approach significantly reduces the amount of code that is needed in your application.

By contrast, for [Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingScenes.html)

> Scenes contain the environments and menus of your game. Think of each unique Scene file as a unique level. In each Scene, you place your environments, obstacles, and decorations, essentially designing and building your game in pieces.

As you can see, these are quite different concepts. I don't see evidence that understanding one would make you more likely to know about the other one.

To address the criteria:

- It's so vague and ambiguous that it says nothing useful about the actual content of the question.
- I have no idea if it's even on-topic because it doesn't mean anything.
- It doesn't add any useful information whatever because it's so vague.
- It does *not* mean the same thing in all common contexts.

Can we burninate this?

Comment: Seems most of the questions are related to [JavaFX's Scenes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javafx/javafx_application.htm) or [Unity's Scenes](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingScenes.html)... (yeah, those are already different entities)

Comment: What is vague and ambiguous about it? Where does it not mean the same thing in common contexts? How many meanings did you find across those 700 questions?

Comment: @rene Even its tag wiki admits that "'scene' can refer to various things." It fundamentally doesn't *mean* anything; what, exactly, is a "scene" in a programming context?

Comment: @rene I counted at least 6 different frameworks that people were asking about on the first page alone. There's no consistency on how this is used and no way to determine which one is "correct."

Comment: @EJoshuaS To be fair, the fact it's used across 6 different frameworks is not really condemning. Quite the opposite: if it means roughly the same thing in all of them, it's an argument that the tag represents a recognized concept in programming. How many programming languages have [tag:loops], after all? I believe this is correct (per Kyle's answer); a "scene" is a kind of unit in programming heavily graphical interfaces. If we can come up with a good description of the concept, updating the tag wiki would be preferred.

Comment: @jpmc26 My concern with that is that the fact that you know about, for example, Unity scenes doesn't really say much about whether you're likely to know about scenes in, for example, JavaFx, so I don't really see how having a single tag for all of those things is likely to help.

Comment: Okay, now we're getting somewhere. Your argument is that they *don't* mean similar things in those different frameworks. Can you edit the post to call that out explicitly and add details and evidence, since that may not be immediately obvious to users who don't work primarily in that field?

Comment: @jpmc26 I edited to include the definitions of a JavaFX scene and a Unity scene - they don't seem similar enough to me to merit keeping the tag around. I'm admittedly not an expert in game development, but I don't see evidence that expertise in one makes you more likely to know about the other ones (which kind of kills the point of having the tag in the first place).

Comment: [*Some folks will seemingly post a request for any tag they come across that isn't interesting to them personally - and then try to justify it with some hand-waving about a lack of experts.*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/158100)

Comment: I'm not completely convinced they're difference concepts. My understanding of a scene (which is also from the position of not being an expert in game development) is roughly "the thing that holds *all* the objects that might need to be rendered, depending on perspective, distance, etc." This would of course be strongly related to the concept of a scene graph. You would have multiple scenes if you have completely different areas that have different logic for what objects they include. Both definitions seem consistent with that.

Comment: @rene My point was that knowledge of one framework doesn't imply any knowledge of the other frameworks. If you only ever know about the subset of [scene] questions that relate to [javafx], for example, then [scene] is redundant at best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So here's the legit use breakdown

- [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) - 142 questions
- [javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx) - 92 questions (excluding any overlap with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java))
- [flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) - 25 questions (5 more are [actionscript-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-3) only)
- [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) - 104 questions

Flash seems to be a minor use so I think we can discount it. Removing it from those questions still leaves them in good shape. So I suggest we make [javafx-scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx-scene) and [unity3d-scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d-scene) as part of the burninate.

Taking those uses out, we still have 415 questions NOT tagged legit. Still seems to be a solid candidate for burnination.

Answer (score 6):

JavaFX has scenes. Unity has scenes. Flash has scenes. None of those specific things have their own tags so there's not necessarily a good alternative tag. And the term "scene" doesn't vary too much in definition between those applications.

I don't know that it needs to be burninated, but I certainly think the description should be updated. You said you didn't know what the tag is supposed to mean, and I suspect anyone who hasn't used an application with scenes wouldn't be able to figure it out from the tag's description:

> 'scene' can refer to various things. Please combine this tag with other tags to put your question into perspective.

Perhaps it could be something like this:

> A way of subdividing a project into manageable areas, like sections of a timeline. The specific implementation of scenes varies between applications (Flash, Unity, etc.), so this should be combined with other tags to provide context.

Comment: No one reads tag descriptions, though.

Comment: @EJoshuaS He does have a good point tho. It is a programming term. We can't let the lack of users reading tag excerpts to be the reason we burn a tag

Comment: @Machavity True - I'm just not convinced that changing the tag description will help much, though. It seems more like a band-aid than a true fix.

Comment: The other problem with this is that, even with the altered tag description, it can't be used as the sole tag. Even if people follow the usage guidance, people who filter only on that tag still won't know exactly what kind of questions they're going to get - there's no reason to suppose that being an expert in Flash scenes would give you any particular insight into Unity scenes, for example, so these don't really have enough in common for the tag to be useful.

Comment: I've made a separate answer to address these concerns. Remember, we don't wan to remove questions that are good so it might be that we just need new specific tags.

Comment: I think the description could be improved a bit by emphasized the graphical nature of scenes, in the context of programming.

Comment: Is one of the requirements for a tag's existence that it still communicates its full meaning when it's the only tag, or that it's a good tag to search by?

Comment: @KyleDelaney My understanding is that tags should be able to stand alone - I can't find the exact quote on Meta offhand right now though.

Comment: @EJoshuaS the quote you are looking for is in the help center. https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging